# extract unique values between columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to extract (as a file) only unique values from 6 columns( 1st column vs (2-6) column) in a data frame. The unique value from one column that does not present any other column.

```
    A              B         C         D          E       F

   12             15         18        55         27      13
   15             25         10        21         23      20
   20             18         14        25         15      25
   25             27         30        35         25      10
                             35                           15
```

The output should looks like...

```
  A       B         C         D         E       F
  12      NA        14        55        23      13
                    30        21
```

Thanking you.

Comment: Hi, can you give us an reproducible example?

Comment: HI user1087590 , Now, How can I compare column A with 5more columns like ColumnA vs B&C&D&E&F. Means genes in column A, which is not present in any other 5 columns. Thanking you.

Comment: Hi are you sure, you have a data.frame? Because the format is not like m*n.
Or are there NA values in the columns so that they have all the same length?
And is it neccessary to have a data.frame in the end or the information in which column the information was originally?
And why in the expected output appears 35 in column A and 13 appears in column B. I would expect 35 in column C and 13 in cloumn F.

Comment: Yes I have a dataframe contains 6 columns and different number of rows like 6500 , 7200, 6750 etc,. But  50 -60% of the genes list (rows) are similar. I want the unique values from each column as a separate single dataframe. Thanks user1087590. you said : "I would expect 35 in column C and 13 in cloumn F" -  No you misunderstood.  I want The unique value from one column that does not present any other column.

Comment: So, if you want the unique values from column A that are not in B, C, D, E, F I would expect only 12 because the 15 is in B, 20 is in F, 25 is in B. right?

Comment: Exactly, now you said. Correct. I want to do this with more than 6000 row values in each column. How can I? Can i get the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want ...

> The unique value from one column that does not present any other
>   column.

A possible solution:

```
> lapply(setNames(1:6, names(df)), function(i) setdiff(df[,i], unlist(df[,-i])))
$A
[1] 12

$B
integer(0)

$C
[1] 14 30

$D
[1] 55 21

$E
[1] 23

$F
[1] 13
```

Note that this is not consistent with your table of expected output but it is consistent with what you say you'd expect (the quote above).

#### formatting the output

```
x <- lapply(setNames(1:6, names(df)), function(i) setdiff(df[,i], unlist(df[,-i])))
l <- sapply(x, length)
x[l==0] <- NA
sapply(x, "length<-", max(l, na.rm=T))
#       A  B  C  D  E  F
# [1,] 12 NA 14 55 23 13
# [2,] NA NA 30 21 NA NA
```

data

```
df <- read.table(text="A              B         C         D          E       F
12             15         18        55         27      13
15             25         10        21         23      20
20             18         14        25         15      25
25             27         30        35         25      10
NA             NA         35        NA         NA      15", header=TRUE)

# dput

df <- structure(list(A = c(12L, 15L, 20L, 25L, NA), B = c(15L, 25L, 
18L, 27L, NA), C = c(18L, 10L, 14L, 30L, 35L), D = c(55L, 21L, 
25L, 35L, NA), E = c(27L, 23L, 15L, 25L, NA), F = c(13L, 20L, 
25L, 10L, 15L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: You are correct lebatsnok, i made a mistake. apologize for that.

Comment: No probs, after corrections the question is clear. I added a little code to format the results the way you wanted .

Comment: Hi lebatsnok, Actually the code is doing fine when i am trying with the df which i have mentioned in this question. But my real data is huge, like full of gene names around more than 6000 from each column. together, all columns  will share atleast 55-60 % of common genes. When am trying with this real data, am not getting any error none results. I donno why, strange. can you help me. Thanks

Comment: When i am executing this code, am getting this error : unique <- lapply(setNames(1:6, names(df)), function(i) setdiff(df[,i], unlist(df[,-i])))
                                                         Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in df[, i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: right. you should replace `df` by the name of your data frame

Comment: in addition, if your real data frame has more variables, you need to make some adjustments. `lapply(1:6, ...`  assumes there are exactly 6 variables. It may be easier first to make a subset of data (just the columns you need) and work on that

Comment: I got some results, but still am getting the genes which is present in other columns also. Ex : i got the gene MYOC  in column A as unique but when i am rechecking with original file the same gene is there in other columns also.

Comment: Check if your variables are factors or character. The code should work with `character` variables but I've no idea what it might proeduce with factors

Answer (score 1):

please try the following:

```
 data$A[!data$A %in% c(data$B, data$C, data$D, data$E, data$F)]
 data$B[!data$B %in% c(data$A, data$C, data$D, data$E, data$F)]
 data$C[!data$C %in% c(data$B, data$A, data$D, data$E, data$F)]
 data$D[!data$D %in% c(data$B, data$C, data$A, data$E, data$F)]
 data$E[!data$E %in% c(data$B, data$C, data$D, data$A, data$F)]
 data$F[!data$F %in% c(data$B, data$C, data$D, data$E, data$A)]
```

Comment: Error in as.vector(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default.

Comment: Hi, please see the changes I made in the answer.

Comment: Thank you user1087590,You saved my day.

Comment: HI user1087590 , Now, How can I compare column A with 5more columns like ColumnA vs B&C&D&E&F. Means genes in column A, which is not present in any other 5 columns. Thanking you.

Comment: @kathirvelk you can create a vector of columns B to F by `c(df$B, df$C, df$D, df$E, df$F)` and then you can compare it in the same way like above.

Comment: Already I have Columns A to F. Can you tell me how to compare (Column A )vs (B-F) . Thank you.

Comment: It works like this: 

`df[!df$A %in% c(df$B, df$C, df$D, df$E, df$F), ]`
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Nothing happening Mr.  user1087590.  I am not getting any unique values. its not showing any errors and results. can you help.

Comment: Thanks. Your code is fine when am trying with my example dataframe which i have given in this question. But coming to my real gene list dataframe the code is giving only the common genes not unique genes, its strange and  the results are automatically saved as values not as dataframe after i used <- symbol also. Can you help Mr. user10877590

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` from the `dplyr` package along with intersect:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!(A %in% intersect(A,B) | B %in% intersect(A,B)))
```

Comment: I have 6035 genes list in column A and 7135 genes in column B. But after executing your command, i got only 6 genes from A and 60 genes from B. But, I know, should get more than 1200 genes. I donno why ?

Comment: Do you want to keep rows where both values are unique or do you want to keep all unique values in both columns and build a dataframe with them?